# Finding out the place values

Tags: javascript

I want to make a function in JavaScript in which if some input is given like `1240` then it gives output as `1000+200+40+0`. Similarly if `16589` then it returns the value like `10000+6000+500+80+9` and so on. Now I want to make a function in JavaScript such that it could returns the values like this but I am somewhere lacking towards the right way, What would be the correct way to proceed?

Comment: How this is connected with `jquery`? It's pure math obvoius.

Comment: ya, I have edited like this pattern  @oGeez

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting an answer purely because it was fun to solve. But really, had you given it a serious try yourself, you probably would have been able to solve this in a few minutes. Make chrome dev tools your best buddy. :-)

```
function express(_number) {

    // s is a string representation of your number
    // o is where the output is generated
    var s = _number.toString(), o = '';

    // while there are more digits
    while(+s > 0) {

        // append a separator if not the first digit
        o += (o !== '' ? ' + ' : '');

        // append the first digit followed by the appropriate number of zeros
        o += (+s.substr(0, 1) * Math.pow(10, s.length - 1)).toString();

        // strip off first digit from the number
        s = s.substr(1);
    }

    // return the result
    return o;
}
```

And you can call it like:

`express(5467)` to get back the string `"5000 + 400 + 60 + 7"`

Comment: thank you very much for your brilliant effort ! thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

Well techfoobar already beat me, and has a better answer, but I already finished mine so Im posting it. Its more....ghetto.

```
function blah(foo)
{
    var foo = foo.toString();
    var finalString = '';
    for ( var i = 0; i < foo.length; i++ )
    {
        var temp = foo.charAt(i);
        for(var j = 1; j < foo.length - i; j++)
        {
              temp = temp.concat('0');
        }
        if (i != foo.length - 1)
              finalString = finalString.concat(temp + '+');
        else
              finalString = finalString.concat(temp);
    }
    return finalString;
}
```

EDIT: It also appears that both of our responses append +0+ if the place value is 0, not sure how that is intended to be handled but can be fixed easily.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all are integers

```
function parseNum(num) {
    return num.toString().split('').reverse().map(function (val, idx) {       
        return val *  Math.pow(10, idx);
    }).reverse().join(' + '); 
}
```

Examples

```
parseNum(1568); //1000 + 500 + 60 + 8
parseNum(98345);//90000 + 8000 + 300 + 40 + 5
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5ZVWx/2/)**</kbd>

Comment: +1 - Super elegant. One minor note though - `num.toString()` is more efficient (and cleaner imo) than `'' + num`, since the former creates just one string instance whereas the second creates 2 (one for the '' and one for the result).

Comment: @techfoobar  thanks.. like you was fun little exercise.